# how to change base url in drupal 8

Tags: 8, database, configuration

I had installed a drupal website inside a folder in web root on an amazon ec2 instance. I used to access it by calling http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/folder .Now that the site is finished i created virtual hosts in my http.conf file to point the domain name to folder. I edited trusted host patterns in settings.php. So far so good! http://mydomainname.com points to front page.

PROBLEM:
when i click on links it shows 404 because path is http://mydomainname.com/folder/link instaed of http://mydomainname.com/link The front page parameter in site settings in admin side is uneditable. 
How can I change that..? Please Help.

Comment: Did you clear caches?

Comment: I tried clearing caches multiple times

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about setting up virtual hosts on the server, which is not influenced from the used CMS.

Comment: Does it work for you when you open the required URL directly, without clicking links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Make sure it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mydomainname.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomainname.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal

<Directory /var/www/html/drupal/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74374/discussion-on-answer-by-no-sssweat-how-to-change-base-url-in-drupal-8).